# How do I make sure nobody gets access to files out of my document root in my websever

Tags: c, server, document-root

I'm currently working on a webserver in C.
I want to make sure that it's impossible to access files that are outside of my document root and I need to write a function that checks the request file / path to that file (for example /index.html) and makes sure there is no way to get out of my document root(for example /../ would make it go out of document root). I was thinking about just checking for ../ and removing that, but then somebody could request ....//, which would be ../ again if we remove ../ out of it. Is there some clever way to do this that I'm not thinking about?

Comment: Are you looking for [the `realpath()` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html)?  It is specified by POSIX, not C itself, but you'll not find anything for this in C itself, because C doesn't specify or depend on any of the details of file names and paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html):

> realpath - return the canonicalized absolute pathname

It will return the absolute pathname, with all symlinks, all `./` and all `/../` resolved. Store your "document root" after resolving it with `realpath` too. After that you can simply `memcmp` or `strcmp` resolved path to document root with the resolved pathname to the path you want to test..